# Recursive challenge in SQL

Tags: sql-server

**I have 2 tables.**

One lists approx 60 root folders with id, in this case "docnumber."

The other table has approx 2.6 million rows in it made up of folders
and documents each with an id of "docnumber" again.  Each row has a type of either F or D depending on whether it is a document or folder.

**Root Table**

*docnumber, name*

100, test

200, anothertest

**Folder/Document Table**

*type, parentnumber, docnumber, name*

D, 500, 600, testdoc

F, 300, 500, testfolder

F, 200, 300, testsubfolder

How can I go through every row of type D in the folder/document table and add a field called TopLevelFolder that will pick out the top level folder from the root table for that document?  It would need to go up through all the folder levels to find the top level folder from the root table.

**Many thanks!**

Comment: What if you have 2 top level folders?

Comment: There's about 60+ top level folders... but each document will have only 1 TOP level folder

Comment: so it is basically simple recursion. if every document has exactly one  parent then how does it different / difficult than many other recursion examples ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you need only a recursive CTE to assemble the hierarchy tree, and a ranking  function to mark the top tier.

```
;WITH Hierarchy AS(
    SELECT ParentNumber, DocNumber, 1 Tier 
    FROM FolderDocument 
    WHERE [Type] = 'D'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT fd.ParentNumber, h.DocNumber, h.Tier + 1
    FROM FolderDocument fd
    INNER JOIN Hierarchy h
    ON fd.DocNumber = h.ParentNumber
    WHERE fd.ParentNumber IS NOT NULL
)
,HierarchyRank AS(
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (
        PARTITION BY h.DocNumber ORDER BY h.Tier DESC) RankNum
    FROM Hierarchy h
)
SELECT hr.DocNumber, hr.ParentNumber AS TopFolderNumber, fdd.Name AS DocName, fdf.Name AS TopFolderName
FROM HierarchyRank hr
LEFT JOIN FolderDocument fdd
ON hr.DocNumber = fdd.DocNumber
LEFT JOIN FolderDocument fdf
ON hr.ParentNumber = fdf.DocNumber
WHERE RankNum = 1
```

Note that this *will* return multiple top-level folders if such exist. If you want to implement a tie-breaker, change the RANK() function to a ROW_NUMBER() and use the ORDER BY clause in the OVER to specify an order that determines the "winner".

This solution also assumes that FolderDocument contains records for the top-level nodes of the tree (which will themselves have null parents). It is simple enough to change the final query to look the top node up from your Root table instead if that is not the case.

I've made a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/30631) to show the handling of multiple top folders and a ragged hierarchy.

**Edit per request:**
To use Root as the source for the parent folder name, you can simply do thus in the final query:

```
SELECT hr.DocNumber, hr.ParentNumber AS TopFolderNumber, fdd.Name AS DocName, r.Name AS TopFolderName
FROM HierarchyRank hr
LEFT JOIN FolderDocument fdd
ON hr.DocNumber = fdd.DocNumber
LEFT JOIN Root r
ON hr.ParentNumber = r.DocNumber
WHERE RankNum = 1
```

Comment: Jonathan, thanks for this.  The FolderDocument table does NOT contain any root folders with NULLs as parents - you would need to refer to the root table for that information.  I'm being a newbie here... but would you be able to add that join in your example above?

Comment: Absolutely spot on that answer Jonathan, many thanks for your help!